# Unsubscribe link in woocommerce email-footer.php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I tried add unsubscribe link to email-footer.php, but can't get recipient email. My code did not work, but maybe can help understand what I need:

```
<?php
$recipient = get_recipient()
?>
<a href="http://mypage.com/unsubscribe?email=<php echo $recipient;?">Unsubcribe me</a>
```

I tried some filters and hooks, but I'm lost in this issue. Can enybody push me forward?

Comment: What return get_recipient() is?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in link.
Correct link should be like:

```
<a href="http://mypage.com/unsubscribe?email='<?php echo $recipient; ?>'">Unsubcribe me</a>
```